# Import to new Paypal Developer Broken

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have logged into the new paypal developer site and clicked import to bring over my old account data which is listed here:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts

When I click on the business TEST account and view the profile of the account, the API credentials (username and password) are blank.  Then when I click the link to the Sandbox Site and try to log in with said test account, it says "Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features.", in which I am already logged in, even if I click the link back to the sandbox. So basically I am stuck..  I need to use the classic API for now and cannot test because the sandbox is evidently broken.

[image: Sandbox Accounts]

Comment: em. have you tried contacting paypal per chance?

Comment: Em, this is where Paypal is sending you to ask question..

Comment: lol that is pretty ghetto my apologies

Comment: would you mind sharing the email address of this particular test account that you are not seeing the API Credentials (in the screenshot above) ? That would help us in troubleshooting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already tried this, please try clearing all of your cache and cookies prior to accessing the developer.paypal.com site.  Also try using a different browser other than IE.  If you can then log in, try to navigate to the test sandbox account and log into your test seller account and view the API credentials from the profile.  There are some issues that are currently being looked into with the launch of the new developer site, and they are being addressed as quickly as possible.

Also as a work around, I am not sure of the testing that you are needing to do specifically but you could try using the API credentials that are included with the SDK.  You would be able to make API calls with those credentials.  However, you would just not be able to sign into the seller account to see those transactions.

If you have not already done so, you may also want to file a ticket with PayPal Merchant Technical Services at www.paypal.com/mts so that they can look into your issue if it is not already being looked into.  By filling out a ticket, this will help to gauge the number of merchants being effected by a particular issue, and this allows you to be notified once the issue is resolved.

Comment: Well, I can sign in now after I cleared the cookies, but as soon as you go to the profile in the sandbox, it gives you that same message again.  All I want is my password and signature for my classic API?  What hoops must I jump through to get this to happen?

Comment: BTW, I have not used IE during this process, but have tried FF and Chrome.

Comment: There is an open issue for this, and it's being worked on.  Until its resolved, you can try using the API credentials in the SDK's for testing.

Comment: Where do I find those credentials exactly?

Comment: You can find them in the different versions of the SDK on PayPal's site, or within the sample code provided as well.  Some samples include this, some may not.  However, I have provided them below.

API Username=sdk-three_api1.sdk.com

API Password=QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q

API Signature=A.d9eRKfd1yVkRrtmMfCFLTqa6M9AyodL0SJkhYztxUi8W9pCXF6.4NI

Comment: So do purchases to paypal pro using the SDK credentials still post back information or does that get lost?

Comment: Yes and No, I guess it depends on how you are trying to get information back to your site.  If you are using the API's, you would receive an API response back to your system.  If you are using IPN, you can pass over an IPN URL in the API request and it would override what is set in the account.  Most API calls support passing over the IPN URL in the API request.

Comment: I am using the API and with those credentials, nothing was passed back to my test code as it normally is.  Mind you, this was working fine until I lost the classic API credentials.  

The biggest problem right now is that I can't view my API info in the sandbox.  What is the direct link to the API section of the profile?  Right now I cant go to the profile page, but I can go to many of the other pages in there (such as update email), but I can't get a listing of the page that lets me click to where I can change the API.  If I could get the direct URL in the SANDBOX to this, maybe it will work?

Comment: It could be different depending on the type of account you have, and the type of credentials you have.  However, you can try this link.  It would take you to your API Signature page if you are using an API Signature.

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-api-signature

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!  Using that, I was able to get to the API Credentials page:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-api-signature